# WLAN speaker to speaker pairing

Tags: wireless, wifi, speakers

Is there a way to connect one speaker to another (I'm building my own ones) using WLAN. The idea was having a host speaker with a WLAN transmitter that could automatically transmit the music playing and this could be picked up by other speakers (the clients) using WLAN receivers.

I have searched the internet for how to get WLAN to do this but to no avail. I would like to know how I can connect and pair two WLAN chips (the host and client) to accomplish this. If coding is needed then I already have an arduino pro micro but if there is a way to do this without coding then that would be preferable.

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: There's no way to do this without writing your own software and also no way to do it with just an arduino. Take a look at the ESP32, maybe that thing is powerful enough for your task.

Comment: What if I used WiFi-Direct? would I still need software then? How difficult would this need to be, I cant imagine it would be too difficult to code something like that that would just stream music out of the WiFi and any receiving client would automatically play it? Or am I being nieve?

Comment: You're looking for WiFi enabled speakers? See Sonos or the hundred other variants. Using Wi-Fi to directly connect two speakers for audio is unnecessarily complex. More than two and you need a host with clients, which likely means a computer. Even just the two is pointless, just use a simpler radio protocol or one designed for it, like Bluetooth.

Comment: WiFi Direct needs way more complex software than a simple access point with some clients connected to it (the SDK of the ESP32 handles most of that for you). You'd need to write server software that runs on the host speaker (or a laptop) and streams the music over TCP, as well as client software that runs on the other speakers and connects to the server. As Samuel already wrote, it would be way better to just use off-the-shelf wireless speakers... But if you want to make your own, that's certainly doable, just a lot of work.

Comment: The wifi lan and especially the buffers required to delay with passing issues will introduce delay, so the gadget would have to delay the local speaker by the same amount.  More typically are one- sender to multiple receiver modes.  Chromecast Audio is an example of a product that can do such a multi-room mode, though setup can be complex and supported sources are limited unless you want to get into a lot of python hackery.  More traditionally, you'd use analog schemes for this rather than packetized ones.

Comment: The main idea is to have a Bluetooth connection to the host from a phone or the like, and then have the WLAN connection between the speakers (no internet access) using, most likely, an ESP2866. Thanks for the help! :) Any other advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using openwrt and 802.11s?  That's the mesh networking built on top of regular old WiFi.  It works pretty well and I've deployed large distributed systems using it.  You can pick up openwrt modules pretty cheaply too.  All you have to do is configure the network and each client then they'll join the mesh and can all talk to one another. That might do what you want.

The tricky part with systems like that is synchronizing the audio.  You don't want one playing a second behind the one in the next room unless they're far enough apart that you can't hear it.  You could work that problem out though I'd think.

As others said there are systems available today commercially that do what you want but if you want to build your own check out 802.11s.  As a bonus each speaker could become a WiFi access point and hop back to your router.  Of course there's latency and bandwidth sharing but still pretty neat I think.